# Can a windows vpc be copied from one computer to another?

Tags: windows-7-x64, vpc

I need to setup a vm using windows virtual pc which i can copy from the creation machine to another computer with win7 and vpc installed. is this even possible? i cant seem to find an answer to this on microsoft vpc web pages.

tia
Ellis

Answer (score 0):

You can, just copy the .vhd file and the other configuration files of the existing vm. Then setup a new vm on the new pc and specify that .vhd file, alternatively just run the config file on the new pc.